# Bing vs google advertising

Tags: advertising, google-ads

is it worth while to advertise using Bing's adcenter if I already have google's adwords?

Comment: Check out browser share in your target market, for example in the UK Google is about 89%, something you should definitely consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your budget, and how much you're willing to spend on advertising. Both are highly used search engines. You could always try a small ad campaign on Bing and after a week or two decide if it's worth it or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it definitely is. You can run very cost effective ad campaigns on Bing. Quite often people focus solely on Google and don't worry about other ad networks which leads to lesser competition. Your mileage may vary, but I would recommend at the very least testing it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth a try, but our experience has been that Bing doesn't generate more than a small fraction of Google's volume.